# Interactively search Parquet-stored data using Apache Spark Streaming and Dataframes

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, parquet

I have significant amount of data stored on my Hadoop HDFS as Parquet files
I am using Spark streaming to interactively receive queries from a web server and transform the received queries into SQL to run on my data using SparkSQL.

In this process I need to run several SQL queries and then return some aggregate result by merging or subtracting the results of individual queries.

Are there any ways I could optimize and increase the speed of the process by, for example, running queries on already received dataframes rather than the whole database?

Is there a better way to interactively query the Parquet stored data and give results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running multiple queries on the same RDD you will get a performance increase by caching the RDD with .cache() before querying it.

Also are you sure that Apache Spark is the right tool for the job here? From the interactive queries that you are describing maybe [Impala](http://impala.io/) or [Presto](https://prestodb.io/) is more suitable.

Comment: I am not really querying the same RDD. I am querying the same Parquet file which is too big to cache.
I am using Spark to leverage in-memory computing .
I thought Spark with SQL and Streaming is better because it allows to do the batch computing, analysis and interactive querying at the same place without having to worry storing the same data in different formats

Comment: [Spark for real time](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/09/spark-sql-real-time-analytics-part2.html)